# Slicer that Filters Matrix Row Subtotal

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a query that is formatted as:

| School | Student ID | Student Name | Section | Course Title | Staff Name | Department | date | Period | Attendance Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 91 | 123456789 | Doe, John | 500 | Science | Winkler, Henry | Science | 07/04/1776 | 1 | A |

This query is made up of over 2 million rows as its every non null value.

I am using a matrix visual with student ID + Name as the rows, Period as column, and the count of attendance code as the value:
[Matrix with out student id and name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYFR1.png)

I want to create a slicer that can filter the row subtotal, but I haven't been able to figure out a method.

I tried creating a count rows measure/custom column, but it did not play well with the other slicers and was fixed at it's value. I'm not sure what dax code to use that will count student id given the attendance code is selected. I've tried

```
period count = calculate(count('Period Attendance'[Student ID]),'Period Attendance'[Attendance Code]=selectedvalue('Period Attendance'[Attendance Code])
```

The column was blank.

I tried a summary table but the slicers wouldn't sort it.

```
Summary Table = SUMMARIZE('Period Attendance','Period Attendance'[Student ID], "Period Count", Count('Period Attendance'[Attendance Code]))
```

Comment: if you want to apply filter to a specific subcategory, you can use [ISINSCOPE](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dax/isinscope-function-dax), this function will apply filter on a specific column